# React - on form submit get POST params

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using React, and would like to retrieve POST params from a form (see below):

```
<form ref='form' className="form">
    <input type="text" className="signup-input" />
    <input type="text" className="signup-input" />
    <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this._onSubmitClick}>Submit</button>
</form>
```

In the `_onSubmitClick` callback, I would like to achieve the same results as calling `$(".form").serialize()` but without using JQuery.

Comment: Have you tried taking a look at the jQuery source to see what it does behind the scenes?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var elements = this.refs.form.getDOMNode().elements;
```

gives you an object containing each of the `input` nodes, which you could then iterate through.

Comment: `getDomNode` is deprecated. 

Do this instead: 

`import { findDOMNode } from 'react-dom'; var elements = findDOMNode(this.refs.form).elements;`

Comment: Look into `FormData`, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData.

Comment: npm module [`form-serialize`](https://github.com/defunctzombie/form-serialize) is worth taking a look. I have used on a project and it has worked well for me.

Answer (score 8):

in addition to the answer i think somebody will love this ;)

```
export default class LoginView extends React.Component {
    handleSubmit(evt) {
        const formData = Array.from(evt.target.elements)
            .filter(el => el.name)
            .reduce((a, b) => ({...a, [b.name]: b.value}), {});
        console.log(formData);
        evt.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }

    render() {
        return (<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>...</form>)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can place `ref` on each `input`:

```
<form ref='form' className="form">
    <input type="text" ref="firstName" className="signup-input" />
    <input type="text" ref="lastName" className="signup-input" />
    <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this._onSubmitClick}>Submit</button>
</form>
```

And then to use `React.findDOMNode` to access them in `_onSubmitClick`:

```
_onSubmitClick: function() {
    var firstName = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.firstName).getValue();
    var lastName = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.lastName).getValue();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: How would I do this, if my input elements are in a child-component?